# Prevent datasheet mode of a standard view?

Tags: 2010, list-view, datasheet

I have a standard view which has columns that should not be editable by everyone but need to be visible in the default view. There is a batch update view that is Datasheet, but I need to make sure that's the only way they can go to a Datasheet view. Is this possible? I thought I could create a Datasheet view and then check the option to restrict Datasheet mode in order to accomplish this, but it seems to not let me even create a Datasheet view in that case. 
Is there another simple way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, my answer was in the question. You just need to create the datasheet view and THEN disable editing in datasheet view. The existing datasheet views are still visible but the standard views cannot be switched to their datasheet counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

The list permissions should handle this for you. Make sure the permissions are set so that only the people who need to update the content have contribute access and everyone else has read only access. The read only folks could go into datasheet mode but they  wouldn't be able to do anything.

Comment: I would need this restriction on contributors so that no contributor is able to switch to datasheet view of the all items view.